# ¿Cómo medir el tiempo de respuesta usando Curl?

Tags: curl

¿Cómo puedo medir el tiempo de respuesta al realizar una llamada (Request) a una página web o a una API usando [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)?

Answer (score 1):

Se puede saber el tiempo de respuesta en segundos usando por linea de comandos:

```
curl -X GET http://www.google.com.ar -s -o /dev/null -w  "Tiempo: %{time_starttransfer} segundos\n"
```

Los parametros son:

**-s** es silenciar el progreso

**-o** es disponer el cuerpo de respuesta a /dev/null.

**-w** Podemos especificar una variedad de formato y en este momento utilicé time_starttransfer para recuperar el tiempo de respuesta (tiempo al primer byte).

**NOTA**: El %-símbolo es un símbolo especial en el entorno Win32, donde todas las ocurrencias del % deben ser duplicadas al usar esta opción.